# how to display the progress of a read_data_function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am loading several huge CSC files into my matlab workspace and I want to show the progress of the functions involved.

My code look something like this

```
x1 = read_data('file_1.ext');
x2 = read_data('File_2.ext');
x3 = read_data('File_3.ext');
x4 = read_data('File_4.ext');
```

Is there a way to show the progress using waitbar?
Alternatively, can I show a simple text based progress in the command window?

Thank you!

Comment: Of course the answer is yes.  I suggest you read the [documentation for `waitbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/waitbar.html). This includes example code that you can adapt to your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, that's what I tried first. But the waitbar leaves me with a four step progress display, 25% after each file has been loaded. That's not what I was looking for. Also the waitbar doc only shows how to implement the waitbar when using a for loop for repeated calculations... and that is not realy what I want to do, right? Am I missing something? Or is there another way to use the waitbar which is not in the doc?